# Unrecognized token 'object': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')↵ at [Source: (String)"[object Object]"; line: 1, column: 8]

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, multipartform-data

I want to pass the value from frontend to backend via API. The format is in **form-data**(in POSTMAN) But, the way I use was giving the error that mention in title.

here is the picture from postmant:

[image]

And here is how I call the API from react.js

```
constructor (props){
        super(props);
        const supplier_id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id'));
        this.state ={
            supplier_id: supplier_id,
            item_name:'',
            item_shortDes: '',
            item_longDes: '',
            price: '',
            terms_agreement: '',
            Location: '',
            selectedFile: null, 
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.createItem = this.createItem.bind(this);
      }
```

```
      createItem(){
        const itemData = this.state
        console.log(itemData)

        const formData = new FormData();    
        formData.append('json', itemData)

        fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/submit`, 
        {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }).then ((result) => {  
                let responseJSON = result;
                console.log(responseJSON);
                });
      }
```

I have no idea what should I going to fix this. Could anyone provide some hint for me about this error? is it I need to make `JSON.stringify`? I

Answer (score 0):

I think because in your postman you send with two key `json` and `itemFile`,
then you can't send all the data inside `json`.

Try this:

```
createItem(){
    // destructuring your data here, seperate json and file
    const {selectedFile, ...rest} = this.state

    const formData = new FormData();    
    formData.append('json', rest)
    formData.append('itemFile', selectedFile) // append the selected file as well

    fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/submit`, 
    {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    }).then ((result) => {  
            let responseJSON = result;
            console.log(responseJSON);
            });
  }
```

I hope it's work